# jqGrid - Displaying only grid like form with data

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have followed the example in creating a new jqGrid.  The data loads and displays ok.  The number of rows works ok.  The only problem is that is just displays the data in plain grid boxes(like below).  No layer.  Even the sort buttons do not show/work.  There is no css effect even though the link is pointed to the correct folder.

```
  col1 |  col2    |  col3
--------------------------
data1a |  data1b  | data1c
--------------------------
data2a |  data2b  | data2c
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../theme/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 50%;
}
</style>

<script src="../theme/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../theme/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../theme/js/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../theme/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=“../theme/js/src/jqDnR.js” type=“text/javascript”></script> 
<script src=“../theme/js/src/jqModal.js” type=“text/javascript”></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'JQ.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['UNIT ID','ROLE ID', 'CREATED DATE','CREATED BY','Inactive'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'UNIT_ID', index:'UNIT_ID', width:55}, 
      {name:'ROLE_ID', index:'ROLE_ID', width:90}, 
      {name:'CREATED_DT', index:'CREATED_DT', width:100}, 
      {name:'CREATED_BY', index:'CREATED_BY', width:80}, 
      {name:'INACTIVE', index:'INACTIVE', width:80, sortable:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30,50],
    sortname: 'UNIT_ID',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: 500,
    height: "100%",
    caption: 'My first gridder'
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: My first gridder UNIT ID  ROLE ID  CREATED DATE  CREATED BY  Inactive 
     
30100 TTT 11-JUN-02 UTECHGE N 
30200 TTT 11-JUN-02 UTECHGE N 
10000 TTT 11-JUN-02 UTECHGE N 
30000 TTT 11-JUN-02 UTECHGE N 
10000 QA-ADMIN 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
20000 TEST-USER 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
20000 QA-ADMIN 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
20100 TEST-USER 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
20100 QA-ADMIN 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
20200 TEST-USER 20-MAY-11 UTECHGE N 
 
    Page  of 4

Comment: Why you include the same JavaScript code many times? Which `grid.loader.js` you use? What is inside? Why you insert `jqModal.js` and `jqDnR.js`? If you use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` from jqGrid 4.0.0 you don't need include `grid.loader.js`, `jqModal.js` and `jqDnR.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't included on your page one **very important** CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Moreover you included **the same** JavaScript code many times, which is wrong? Which `grid.loader.js` you use? What is inside? You can open it with any text editor. Why you insert `jqModal.js` and `jqDnR.js`? If you use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` from jqGrid 4.0.0 you don't need include `grid.loader.js`, `jqModal.js` and `jqDnR.js`. The exact contain of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` can depend on the list of modules which you selected as you downloaded the jqGrid. You can open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and examine the comment line at the beginning of the file. The standyrd (full) version of the file contain the following modules:

> Modules: grid.base.js;
>   jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js;
>   grid.common.js; grid.formedit.js;
>   grid.filter.js; grid.inlinedit.js;
>   grid.celledit.js; jqModal.js;
>   jqDnR.js; grid.subgrid.js;
>   grid.grouping.js; grid.treegrid.js;
>   grid.import.js; JsonXml.js;
>   grid.tbltogrid.js; grid.jqueryui.js;

So you must not inclde the same modules one more time.

Comment: @gt: You are welcome! What was the main problem? Could I help you?